# Error 402 - Firebase quota storage exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Let me breakdown of what happened. Yesterday I tried to insert some videos from firebase realtime database to my app in the form of recyclerview and the first 2 testing with my physical device, it went fine but then during the third time testing, my app suddenly didn't work and when I checked what was going on, It said this.**"V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service"** Then when I went into further analysis I soon came to realize it had this error as in the code.

```
{
 "error": {
   "code": 402,
   "message": "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to 
    learn more.",
   "status": "ACCESS_BUCKET"
 }
```

}

Im very sure that my storage is less than 100 mb but yet I got this result. However, today it's back working but I want to know what kind of action would invoke this error provided that I have ample of storage that is yet to be used.. Any help to clarify the issue that I went through would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I changed the tags on your question. Given the `ACCESS_BUCKET` in the error message, it seems that the message is triggered from Cloud Storage, and not the Realtime Database.

Comment: but I am using Real Time Database, how will that trigger the Cloud Storage?

Comment: You uploaded video to the Realtime Database? I'd definitely reconsider that if I were you. And the "bucket" in the error message really hints at it coming from Cloud Storage. Can you edit your question to include the code that triggers that error message?

Answer (score 1):

There are more quota than just the total size of the bucket. From the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing):

> Storage
>
> GB stored: 5 GB
>
> GB downloaded: 1 GB/day
>
> Upload operations: 20K/day
>
> Download operations: 50K/day

Given your description you exceeded one of the daily limits, likely the bandwidth usage, which is 1 GB/day. That would also explain why it started working again on the next day.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the limelight, but i'm wondering, how can 5 videos would make the bandwidth exceed that much? I