# Could not load files; quota has been exceeded for this project

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

[image: 1]

Hi everyone.
i'm a flutter developer(Beginner). I created a simple app in flutter and using Firebase. Only 15 users use this app last 24hrs. Now, I got this error message in firebase Storage. and then, in my app, images are not loaded.

1.How solve this problem and restart firebase storage?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage has a free usage limit of 1GB downloads per day, regardless of the number of users, and is documented in the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#cloud-storage). If you get this message, you've exceeded that download limit or another one from the link.

Check the <kbd>Usage</kbd> tab that is right there in the screenshot to see the recent usage for your project.

Also see:

- [Firebase cloud storage quota has been exceeded for this project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698715/firebase-cloud-storage-quota-has-been-exceeded-for-this-project-error)
- [Error 402 - Firebase quota storage exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047880/error-402-firebase-quota-storage-exceeded)
- [Firebase Storage Exceed Quota Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817141/firebase-storage-exceed-quota-limit)
- [Firebase storage Quota has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361517/firebase-storage-quota-has-been-exceeded)